# UITextView not scrolling to top when using textContainerInset

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I am using a `UITextView` to add an image and some `attributedText` to:

```
self.textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
self.textView.editable = NO;
self.textView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
[self.textView setAttributedText:attrStr];
```

I then need to set the `textContainerInset` since I added the image as a subview (I want it to scroll with the text) so that the text doesn't go over the image.

```
self.textView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(insetTop, 8, 8, 8);
```

But, for some reason, on iPad when loading it is scrolled to the bottom. So, I try to scroll to the top when loading using:

```
[self.textView scrollRangeToVisible:NSMakeRange(0, 0)];
```

But, that doesn't work. Removing the `textContainterInset` DOES allow it to scroll.

How can I still use the `textContainerInset` and scroll to the top? And should I be using a `UIScrollView` instead to add my subviews to?

Comment: Can you scroll it manually (with your finger)?

Comment: @Undo - Yes. And by tapping the status bar.

Comment: Sounds it it is a bug, submitted a radar for it. #18572152